# How does session of chainbase work?

Tags: data-storage, chainbase, net

Do you have any knowledge about session of chainbase (It means: Each user we can create a session in chainbase and this session exits util user who be deleted. And The session contains many transactions)? Please share to me, thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "session of chain base" in your question.  I strongly feel that if you do that you will have a better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Thank @Nat, I just edit my answer. Sorry I am bad english

Comment: No problem!  I try hard to be sympathetic to those that aren't native English speakers.  I couldn't imagine having to learn a second language and then communicate on a technical topic like this.  Just trying to make sure you get a good answer!  Your question is still difficult to understand.  Telegram is a very good place to ask questions as well! I would recommend asking either `@sandw1ch` or `@tbfleming` in the EOS Developers Telegram channel: https://t.me/joinchat/Esi1OkPktgcFeJ3Lmlcrqg The group is very friendly and helpful!

Comment: Thank you very much, I hope get answer from them. Thank you!

Comment: You may connect to node use WebSocket. If I understand what you mean)